# Cannot figure out what's happening with my os.listdir method - python

Tags: python, tensorflow-slim

I'm using tensorflow-slim, and modified some of sample code to use my own data.

Below is the original code to set the directory to download the dataset(dataset_dir is given by user input, which was '/tmp/flowers' this time):

```
flower_root = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'flower_photos')
directories = []
class_names = []
print('##################current dir is', flower_root)    #original line for verification
for filename in os.listdir(flower_root):
  path = os.path.join(flower_root, filename)
  if os.path.isdir(path):
    directories.append(path)
    class_names.append(filename)
```

It prints '##################current dir is /tmp/flowers\flower_photos', which is correct, and it actually works well for the whole code.

Since it works well, I tried to customize the code as below, which is just replacing 'flowers' with 'MyData'(and therefore changing dataset_dir into '/tmp/MyData'):

```
MyData_root = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'MyData_photos')
directories = []
class_names = []
print('##################current dir is', MyData_root)
for filename in os.listdir(MyData_root):
  path = os.path.join(MyData_root, filename)
  if os.path.isdir(path):
    directories.append(path)
    class_names.append(filename)
```

This time, it prints '##################current dir is /tmp/MyData\MyData_photos', which is also correct, but it raises an error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/tmp/MyData\\MyData_photos'

I've been working on for this problem for a few hours, but I cannot understand what happened to that os.listdir(MyData_root) method. It suddenly inserts additional '\' between 'MyData' and 'MyData_photos' and causes an error.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question so it is a [mre] - this means I should be able to paste it into a file and run it _without adding anything_. Doing this (and testing it yourself before you edit it in) means people reading your question can try it for themselves and are __much__ more likely to respond with comments and answers.

Comment: BTW add a few print statements so you see the values of important variables. Don’t worry about the double \ except that if you’re on Linux os.path.join shouldn’t be using \